# how to increase "call volume quota" for azure apim?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I'm calling a service via a request to Azure APIM and I just received a 403 response with the following error message: "Out of call volume quota.  Quota will be replenished in 00:40:14." How can I update APIM or Azure in general to workaround this constraint?

Comment: What pricing tier are you using?

Comment: I had the same problem. I found out that I was using the minimum (free) pricing tier, which allows 1000 calls per month. Search for your resource in Azure Studio and change your subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Use an API management key (product subscription). Without the key you fall into the "Starter" product, which has a call volume quota.

https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/api-management-howto-product-with-rules/

The other way is to increase the quota, go to the policies on APIM and select "Starter", there should be a call rate quota in there.