# Out of Call Volume Quota

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I've been on the $250 Trial (Cognitive Search) since December 16th. Today, I'm see this when our web app attempts to pull Bing search results:

> Error 403. Out of call volume quota. Quota will be replenished in 17.03:21:36.

Other than waiting, is there a way to resolve this? What is the Quota, and where can it be checked? Odd given that our site is still under development, with very little traffic. Literally a few outside hits per day.

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35286963/367865

Comment: Thanks, I did see that. Don't think it applies, however. MS does claim to monitor posts to this forum, so hopefully they will respond. No other support options.

Comment: I'm reasonably confident that Microsoft supports this product directly.  You should look into contacting them directly.

Comment: I did, but once I selected Technical Support as support option, I was referred here unless I upgraded by subscription. Seems they do not provide technical support for trial subscriptions.

Comment: Now MS support refers to a help article written in Dutch. Prior to that I tried searching their Azure support forum, but it hangs and then returns server errors. On top of that, their support appears to be outsourced to India or Pakistan, which can make communication awkward at times. Gotta imagine Google would be easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the API key either isn't getting passed properly or is running into a very small quota.

This link may help, in particular the part using the developer console to ensure the API key is valid: ["Bing Error - Out of call volume quota" on first use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039621/bing-error-out-of-call-volume-quota-on-first-use?rq=1)

When you created the Cognitive Search API what rate package did you select--what are the usage limits for it?  See this thread, where that was the issue: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7b39925f-595b-4a0b-8919-e3cbd8f17b1c/cognitive-search-requests-with-api-keys-generated-in-azure-console-return-401s?forum=azureapimgmt

BTW, I've never actually used the Cognitive Services APIs myself, though I've used other Azure API Management managed APIs.

Comment: Thanks, but not the problem. Worked for weeks until few days ago. I believe I know what the problem is. $250 credit for some reason was unpinned from trial subscription. So, became trial S1 which went 403 when 100o quota hit. Working with MS billing. The new Azure has many problems.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved exactly the same issue similarly to how Daniel Abrams said in the comments here.

It turned out that despite the free trial credits applied to my account, there are still some invisible limits. Even though I only spent less than a dollar from that trial subscription, there was a limit placed on my account that would reset in 5 days.

Changing to a normal paid subscription resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get data from API till I ran 2 parallel codes using same key, then it blocked me, so it can also be an issue of speed as well as limited hits per hour. 
You cannot hit the API more no. of times/sec than it allows.