# Bing Error - Out of call volume quota

Tags: azure

Using Blockspring to access Bing Web Search to return URLs based upon the name of companies (https://www.blockspring.com/tutorials/excel-company-urls) I am receiving this:

> ERROR! Bing Error - Out of call volume quota. Quota will be replenished in 15.01:52:46

Even though my Microsoft Cognitive Services account shows zero of 1,000 calls used.

Comment: Probably would help if you showed your code. And specified the exact API you're calling.

Comment: Also - seems like a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41405545/out-of-call-volume-quota) (though there's no definitive answer posted). Maybe better to upvote that question? (although, like yours, that other question also omits pertinent information and calling code).

Comment: Just using the Bing Search API. There is no code, because I am using the tool Blockspring.

Comment: Try this: https://open.blockspring.com/apps.